# R obs Number Limited

Tags: r

I've been stuck with the data here for days, as I want to get data from API Binance, which is surely over ten thousand obs, but the R only limited the obs at 1500L.

I have been advised to use loop, but it doesn't help any.

Any help would be totally my gratitude!

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(lubridate)

# api description:
#
get
  ("https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md"
  )

#klinecandlestick-data

options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

url  <- "https://api.binance.com"

path <- "/api/v3/exchangeInfo"

raw.result <- GET(url = url, path = path)

not.cool.data <- rawToChar(raw.result$content)

list1 <- fromJSON(not.cool.data)

list <- list1$symbols$symbol

klines2 <- rbindlist(lapply(
  c('LTCTUSD', 'LTCBNB'),
  binance_klines,
  interval = '30m',
  start_time = '2017-01-01', 
  end_time = '2021-01-08'
))
names(klines2)
sapply(klines2, function(x) length(unique(x)))

klines2
df.1 <- list.files(pattern = "2017-2021")
df.1_r <- vector(mode = integer,
                 length = length(klines2))

tickling <- unique(klines2$symbol)
tickling
low <- c()
high <- c()
  for (symbol in tickling) {
    look.at <- klines2$symbol == symbol
    low <- append(low,min(symbol$low[look.at]))
    high <- append(high, max(symbol$high[look.at]))
  }
tickling
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to load data from API but it limitedly comes at 2000 obs, in fact, there are more of obs but it is limited to 2000 obs only